# Faulty Arduino Logic?

Tags: serialization, arduino, switch-statement, led

I am making a simple Led program that will be turned into a library for my project. I have created four methods that will allow you to A) Setup as many Led pins as you want and make them as Outputs. B) Flash the Led lights at a customized time. C) Turn On Leds. D) Turn Off Leds. Everything is working if i just run the methods in the void loop(). For example:

```cpp
Void loop(){

flashLed(pinNum, 2000);
turnOf(pinNum);
turnOn(pinNum);
}
```

If i run the above code it works fine, however it keeps looping as its obviously in a loop. So i decided to start the serial com by using Serial.begin(9600) in the setup(), and then testing for the serial com and used a switch case statement in order to appropriately implement these methods. What am i doing wrong here? i get no errors at all. When i type into the serial monitor nothing happens, i believe my logic is fine but that is why i am here. When anything is typed into the serial monitor, the code runs the default in the switch case statement and that is all. I have tried using while, if to no avail. Also tested the inverse of serial which would be !serial.available() Here is my code:

```cpp
//Define the pin numbers
byte pinNum[] = {4, 3, 2};


void setup() {
  //Setup the ledPins
  ledSetup(pinNum);
  Serial.begin(9600);  
}

void loop() {

  while(Serial.available() > 0){
    //Read the incoming byte
    byte ledStatus = Serial.read();
    switch (ledStatus){
      case 0: 
      turnOff(pinNum);
      Serial.println("The Leds Have Been Turned Off");
      break;
      case 1:
      turnOn(pinNum);
      Serial.println("The Leds Have Been Turned On");
      break;
      case 2:
      flashLed(pinNum, 1000); //This will make the Led blink for half a second
      Serial.println("The Leds Will Begin Flashing");
      break;
      default:
      flashLed(pinNum, 1000); //This will make the Led blink for half a second
      break;
    }
  }
}

//Method to declare the pins as output
void ledSetup(byte ledPins[]){
  for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(ledPins); i++){
    pinMode(ledPins[i], OUTPUT);
  }
}

//Method to blink the Led light/lights
void flashLed(byte ledBlink[], int duration){
  //Time is divided by two because it takes 2 seconds 
  //to run the sketch 
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(ledBlink); i++){
  digitalWrite(ledBlink[i], HIGH);
  delay(duration/2);
  digitalWrite(ledBlink[i], LOW);
  delay(duration/2);
}
}

//Method to turn Leds off
void turnOff(byte ledOff[]){
  for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(ledOff); i++){
    digitalWrite(ledOff[i], LOW);
}
}

//Method to turn Leds On
void turnOn(byte turnOn[]){
for (int i = 0; i <= sizeof(turnOn); i ++){
  digitalWrite(turnOn[i], HIGH);

}
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Try replace `0, 1, 2` in the `case` tests with `'0', '1', '2'`, because you are most likely sending *ASCII* encoded digits.

Comment: Sorry! Debugger was of no use as there was no errors given. I gave a minimal, complete, and verifiable source at the start of the question. Although these categories may vary subjectively, sorry if i broke any rules. Thanks Patrick will try.

Comment: Patrick, you have solved my question! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Do you use the  *debugger* for *Arduino* of [Visual Studio](http://www.visualmicro.com/page/Arduino-Visual-Studio-Downloads.aspx)? or the one of *Atmel Studio*? These are the only two I have ever heard of, though I've personally never used either of these. `Serial.print()` is usually more than enough for most issues you might encounter. i.e. in your case `Serial.println(ledStatus)` should have printed `48` after you entered `0` on *serial monitor*.

Comment: debugging is not about removing warnings/errors but to spot algorithm errors by investigating variable state against their expected state in runtime ....

Comment: I understand, this would be the perfect place to add breakpoints and step trough the code to compare the variable state. I am using the Arduino IDE debugger Patrick.

Comment: Strange enough, my version of *Arduino IDE* has no debugging feature.

Comment: I am sorry Patrick i meant i am using the Arduino IDE as a development environment. For debugging i am using the Visual Studio plugin. I dont think the Arduino IDE has a built in debugger. Prior to this, i did not know i could simply debug using serial.print. With visual studio, there was no error given when stepping through.

Comment: Patrick, if you want, i can pick your answer since your answer did solve my problem. In case other people have similar problems, it might be helpful if this question changes to answered. I think you are going to have to answer and not comment though.

Comment: @ErickRamirez I did it. If you could edit your question to make it a bit more to the point and fix the title to be match your actual problem, in a way that someone else might find this question through search, then I'll upvote it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *serial monitor* sends symbols encoded in the **ASCII** format.

**e.g.** when you enter `0`, `Serial.read()` returns `48`, which is the *ASCII* code for digit `0`. Since the value `48` is not listed in the following cases, the *default* branch is taken:

```cpp
      case 0: ...
      case 1: ...
      case 2: ...
      default: ...
```

---

There are **many** solutions to your problem.

**1.** change `case` conditions to match what you are sending:

```
      case '0': ...
      case '1': ...
      case '2': ...
```

**2.** replace `Serial.read()` with `Serial.parseInt()`:

```
    int ledStatus = Serial.parseInt();
```

This will actually work with more general inputs, e.g. `123`, but it will return `0` if there is anything different from a *digit* in the input buffer.

**3.** wrap `Serial.read()` within `atoi()`:

```
    byte ledStatus = atoi(Serial.read());
```

This is somewhat more limited than both of previous options, since now you can only have `10` cases in your switch.